# How to configure secondary axis in matplotlib plot when the axis relation is derived empirically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to follow this documentation

> https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html

in the third case of secondary axes transform, i.e., when "we want to relate the axes in a transform that is ad-hoc from the data, and is derived empirically", thus, setting "the forward and inverse transforms functions to be linear interpolations from the one data set to the other.". But I couldn't achieve a satisfactory result.

Consider, for instance, the simple plot of the first example of this documentation: sine wave with two horizontal axis, where one is a conversion of radians to degrees on the same plot.

The code bellow gives the right result, where the bottom axis is in radians and the top axes is in degrees

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)

def deg2rad(x):
    return x * np.pi / 180

def rad2deg(x):
    return x * 180 / np.pi

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(rad2deg,deg2rad))

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, the code bellow intends to simulate that the "degree axes" would come from empirical data (array variable `xnew`, which could be other values), but it doesn't give the right result (following the interpolation functions of the documentation).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)

xold = x
xnew = x * 180 / np.pi

def forward(x):
    return np.interp(x, xold, xnew)

def inverse(x):
    return np.interp(x, xnew, xold)

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(forward,inverse))

plt.show()
```

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both the forward and the inverse functions are called for values that are slightly out of the range of the given x-values. For example, they are used for the xlims. (One could add a `print(x)` inside these functions to see how they are called.)

If these functions are written as a simple linear transformation such as in `deg2rad` example, there is no problem. The function works equally outside of its bounds. But a `np.interp` doesn't have a good clue outside its range, so it returns its lower or upper limit. This cut-off causes the undesired tick labelling.

For a part, this could be remedied by setting a tight x-axis, so without the padding that happens default:

```
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

But even then the undesired tick at 400 pops up.

A better solution is to make the range for both functions a bit wider than the limits shown on old x-axis, including the padding. For example, setting

```py
xold = np.linspace(x[0]-0.5, x[-1]+0.5, 100)
xnew = xold * 180 / np.pi
```

Note that in the [linked example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html), they set `xold = np.arange(0, 11, 0.2)`, but then only do a plot starting from the third index to create enough room for the padding: `ax.plot(xold[3:], xnew[3:])`.

The complete example could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)

xold = np.linspace(x[0]-0.5, x[-1]+0.5, 100)
xnew = xold * 180 / np.pi

def forward(x):
    return np.interp(x, xold, xnew)

def inverse(x):
    return np.interp(x, xnew, xold)

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(forward,inverse))

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, this really answers the question. Sorry, I forgot to interact before.
I really missed that the example started from the third index (`xold[3:]`). I should have noted it.