# Adding Secondary y axis to a 4x4 subplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to a line and bar chart.  I am comparing percentages to full numbers and would like to add a secondary y axis to all the charts.  Here's what Code and visuals I currently have

```
x1 = sales_dashboard_monthly_salesperson['leads_per_rep']
x2 = sales_dashboard_monthly_salesperson['close_per_rep']
x3 = sales_dashboard_monthly_salesperson['num_deals_start']
x4 = sales_dashboard_monthly_salesperson['marked_won']
y1 = sales_dashboard_monthly_salesperson['close%']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].bar(x, y1)
axs[0, 0].plot(x, x2)
axs[0, 0].set_title('leads_per_rep vs close %')
axs[0, 1].scatter(x1, x2, c = 'g')
axs[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0, 1]')
axs[1, 0].scatter(x1, x2, c = 'g')
axs[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1, 0]')
axs[1, 1].bar(x, x4, )
axs[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1, 1]')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='x-label', ylabel='y-label')

# Hide x labels and tick labels for top plots and y ticks for right plots.
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.label_outer()
```

[image: four_charts]

Here's what I want all four to look like:

[image: double y axis]

with the two y axis specifically!

Comment: Did you try `ax.secondary_yaxis`?  If so, what didn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure secondary axis in matplotlib plot when the axis relation is derived empirically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761902/how-to-configure-secondary-axis-in-matplotlib-plot-when-the-axis-relation-is-der)

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'secondary_yaxis' is what it said when I tried that

Comment: `axs` is an ndarray.  `ax=axs[0, 0]` returns `ax` which is an axes.