# Secondary x-axis via np.interp: how to change xlims

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have datasets of X and Y, which I plot. For each value of X I have another dataset. I want to plot 2 x-axes in matplotlib. The problem is that the datasets for x are not dependent on each other.

I tried [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761902/how-to-configure-secondary-axis-in-matplotlib-plot-when-the-axis-relation-is-der/60767083#60767083?newreg=74bd785aef7148a1a8c8fa9a1862e001). When I have no x-lims, it works well.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as npfig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
    
x_upper = np.array([2.379618e-29,5.895669e-29,1.018725e-28,
                    1.413803e-28,1.780809e-28,2.080620e-28,
                    2.287013e-28,2.603605e-28,2.810124e-28])
    
x_lower = np.array([20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100,120])

y = np.array([-1.333526e-16,-8.841676e-16,-2.803599e-15,
              -5.300285e-15,-7.723194e-15,-9.906261e-15,
              -1.124626e-14,-1.238456e-14,-1.193596e-14])
ax.plot(x_lower, y)
    
xold = x_lower
xnew = x_upper
    
def forward(x):
    return np.interp(x, xold, xnew)
    
def inverse(x):
    return np.interp(x, xnew, xold)
    
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(forward,inverse))
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

[image: Without x-lim]

However, in the upper x-axis, always the values `0` and `3e-28` are shown. How to get rid of them?

The next problem is when I change the lower axis limit:

```
ax.set_xlim(15, 125)
```

The values are still there, but now the lower x-axis and the upper x-axis don't match their values. Could you please help me fix it?

[image: With x-lim]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the `1e-28` suffix, since the values are so small, I'd scale them up and then annotate the axis label appropriately:

[image]

Modifications:

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "dejavuserif" #<--- serif math text

...

x_upper = np.array([2.379618e-29,5.895669e-29,1.018725e-28,
                    1.413803e-28,1.780809e-28,2.080620e-28,
                    2.287013e-28,2.603605e-28,2.810124e-28]) * 1e28  #<--- scale

y = np.array([-1.333526e-16,-8.841676e-16,-2.803599e-15,
              -5.300285e-15,-7.723194e-15,-9.906261e-15,
              -1.124626e-14,-1.238456e-14,-1.193596e-14]) * 1e15    #<--- scale
...

#Label axes
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y~(\times10^{15})$')           
secax.set_xlabel(r'$x_{new}~(\times 10^{28})$')  
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

As for the second issue, where you extend the bounds beyond `x_old` and `x_new` becomes misaligned - this is because you are extrapolating outside the range of the data, so by default `np.interp` will just copy the edge values as it can't deal with values outside of the range.

To get round this, you can pad the original values with some extrapolated data, so that `np.interp` can perform interpolation within that padded range. This is the new result when setting `ax.set_xlim(15, 125)`:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "dejavuserif" #<--- serif math text

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

x_upper = np.array([2.379618e-29,5.895669e-29,1.018725e-28,
                    1.413803e-28,1.780809e-28,2.080620e-28,
                    2.287013e-28,2.603605e-28,2.810124e-28]) * 1e28  #<--- scale

y = np.array([-1.333526e-16,-8.841676e-16,-2.803599e-15,
              -5.300285e-15,-7.723194e-15,-9.906261e-15,
              -1.124626e-14,-1.238456e-14,-1.193596e-14]) * 1e15    #<--- scale

x_lower = np.array([20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100,120])

#for tick labels - pad outside data bounds
pad_n_pts = 5

dUp_dLow = np.gradient(x_upper, x_lower)
x_upper_padded = np.insert(
    x_upper,
    [0, len(x_upper)],
    [x_upper[0] - pad_n_pts * np.diff(x_lower)[0] * dUp_dLow[0],
     x_upper[-1] + pad_n_pts * np.diff(x_lower)[-1] * dUp_dLow[-1]]
)

#for tick labels - pad outside data bounds
dLow_dUp = np.gradient(x_lower, x_upper)
x_lower_padded = np.insert(
    x_lower,
    [0, len(x_lower)],
    [x_lower[0] - pad_n_pts * np.diff(x_upper)[0] * dLow_dUp[0],
     x_lower[-1] + pad_n_pts * np.diff(x_upper)[-1] * dLow_dUp[-1]]
)

ax.plot(x_lower, y)

#Use padded x for interpolation
def forward(x):
    return np.interp(x, x_lower_padded, x_upper_padded)
    
def inverse(x):
    return np.interp(x, x_upper_padded, x_lower_padded)

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(forward,inverse))

ax.set_xlim(15, 125)

#Label axes
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y~(\times10^{15})$')           
secax.set_xlabel(r'$x_{new}~(\times 10^{28})$')  
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

The figure below shows the relationship between the original data points and the extrapolated points. You `set_xlim` to only slightly outside the blue points, so the below is likely a good-enough approximation. The extrapolation would be less accurate if you were to `set_xlim` well outside the blue points.

[image]

```
#View padding in relation to original
plt.scatter(x_lower_padded, x_upper_padded, label='original')
plt.scatter(
    x_lower_padded[[0, -1]], x_upper_padded[[0, -1]],
    marker='*', s=200, c='tab:orange', label=f'extrapolated {pad_n_pts} points'
)
plt.gca().set(xlabel='$x_{lower}$', ylabel='$x_{upper}$')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 2.5)
plt.gcf().legend(loc='right', fontsize=9)
plt.gca().set_title('Original vs. extrapolated axis bounds')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I reall appreciate your help and solution.